# Is there a way to set the command in a Tkinter Button at run time without Eval()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

As the title says is there another way to get this python script to set the command for a button at run time without using eval(), I'm aware it's a really - really - stupid way of  doing it but I can't for the life of me work out how else to do it.

The Command needs to be set when creating each button object and as such I can't preset it.

I've tried regular input and fstring input but can't think of anything else, any help would be appreciated

```
root = Tk()
root.title("SOP")
root.geometry("1920x1080")

class CreateGui(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        myFrame = Frame(master)
        myFrame.pack()

    def CreateButton(self, lines, target):
        self.myButton = Button(self.master, text=lines, command=eval(target))
        print(target)
        self.myButton.pack(pady=20)

    def clicker(self):
        print("you clicked a button")

GUI = CreateGui(root)
GUI.CreateButton("Click Me!", "self.clicker")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I mean, the simplest way would just be to remove `eval` and just pass in `GUI.clicker`

Comment: It's highly unusual to pass a string with the name of the function rather than the actual function. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2):

how about changing command to `command=target`, and changing the createButton call to `GUI.CreateButton("Click Me!", GUI.clicker)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions and instance methods (or rather *callables*, as the documentation calls them) are objects too. They are obects to which the "function call" operation can be applied. See the "Data model" chapter in the Python language reference.

In Python, variables are basically reference to objects.
So you can create multiple references to the same function. And you can use those to call it.

See the example below. In #3 we create another reference to the same function.

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return "bar"
   ...:     

In [2]: type(foo)
Out[2]: function

In [3]: test = foo
Out[3]: <function __main__.foo()>

In [4]: test()
Out[4]: 'bar'

In [5]: foo()
Out[5]: 'bar'
```

As you can see, you can use both `test` and `foo` to call the same function. In fact, they both reference the same object:

```
In [6]: id(foo)
Out[6]: 34429417360

In [7]: id(test)
Out[7]: 34429417360
```

So when you create a `Button` you can just pass it a function object.

---

> The Command needs to be set when creating each button object

That is not the case.

You can create a button without specifying a command:

```
self.myButton = Button(self.master, text=lines)
```

And you can set the command (like many other widget properties) later using dictionary syntax:

```
self.myButton['command'] = self.clicker
```

Now the `command` property of `myButton` is a reference to the `self.clicker` method.